# Биоинформатический анализ или биоинформационный?

Tags: прилагательные

В переводимом документе наткнулся на "**биоинформатический** анализ посттрансляционной модификации".

Является ли прилагательное "биоинформатический" верным или допустимым вариантом, или же следует всегда писать "биоинформационный"?

P.S.

Контекст - заголовок раздела в документе, посвященном разработке лекарственного средства (белка). Язык оригинала - русский (я перевожу на английский). Раздел содержит генетический код белка, в котором цветом выделены возможные сайты модификации (гликозилирование, окисление и т.п.)

Comment: Контекст - наше всё! И если есть, то на языке оригинала. По первому впечатлению здесь употребленное слово не синоним биоинформационному.

Comment: @behemothus - контекст - заголовок раздела в документе, посвященном разработке лекарственного средства (белка). Язык оригинала - русский (я перевожу на английский). Раздел содержит генетический код белка, в котором цветом выделены возможные сайты модификации (гликозилирование, окисление  и т.п.)

Comment: Перенес в текст ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ой, как я был неправ...*

**Биоинформатический** - относящийся к **биоинформатике**. К сожалению, этот термин пока не фиксируется словарями. Но он логичен, в то время как нормативное "биоинформационный" вызывает вопросы,поскольку отсылает к некоей "биоинформации" (а что это?), а не к биоинформатике.

Думаю, со временем этот вопрос решится в пользу "биоинформатики" или путем разделения значений.

Короче, я бы оставил на совести переводчика.

(+)

> @behemothus - контекст - заголовок раздела в документе, посвященном
>   разработке лекарственного средства (белка).

В документе идет речь об информации (кодируемой белками) или об информатике (науке)?

> Раздел содержит генетический код белка, в котором цветом выделены
>   возможные сайты модификации

Тогда использование "информатики" тут выглядит странным. Похоже на биоинформацию и, следовательно, на "бионформационный".

> Язык оригинала - русский (я перевожу на английский).

Тогда по логике надо бы довериться автору.

В затруднении я. Не просить же вас всю статью дать почитать...
Наверное, все-таки уважение к авторскому чутью тут должно перевесить. Не с потока же он этот термин взял

Comment: Насколько я понял, код белка (текст) загрузили в некую программу, которая выдала обратно тот же код, но с пометками в тех позициях, где возможны модификации (после производства белка в клетке). Получается, была использована "биоинформатика". Интересно.

Comment: Нет, статью я не могу дать почитать, это документ для внутреннего потребления, так сказать. ^_^ И я даже не думал обращаться к автору - там есть вопросы поважнее. Просто мне стало любопытно. Большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: *Получается, была использована "биоинформатика"*. - Теперь понятно. Ну да, автор точен, хотя и ненормативен. Тогда все вопросы в общем-то снимаются. А статью - избави Боже, это ж сарказм был.

Answer (score 0):

Это абсолютные синонимы.

См.:

1) **[биоинформатический анализ](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7&rlz=1C1AOHY_ruRU709RU709&oq=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.1476j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**;

2) **[биоинформационный анализ](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7)**.

Биоинформационные методы,биоинформатические исследования (статья "[Биоинформатика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)").